# How can I remove a Hybrid Connection that's shown in the Hybrid Connection Manager UI application?

Tags: azure-hybrid-connections

I've been experimenting with Microsoft's Azure Hybrid Connections and have found that the UI tool for managing the on-premises configuration (called Hybrid Connection Manager UI) doesn't seem to have any way to remove connections once they're added.

Answer (score 5):

It seems that the entries created in the UI tool are simply stored in the configuration file for the Azure Hybrid Connection Manager Service (windows service). So if you edit `C:\Program Files\Microsoft\HybridConnectionManager 0.7\Microsoft.HybridConnectionManager.Listener.exe.config` and remove entries within the `<connectionStrings>` element, they'll disappear from the UI tool.

You may need to restart the Windows service and refresh to see that happen.